# Getting: "There were deployment errors". Continue? While trying to debug a service fabric application

Tags: debugging, deployment, azure-service-fabric

I have set up the service fabric application in my local cluster. But when I try to debug the application, I am getting " There were deployment errors" but I am not able to see any errors in output screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Service Fabric projects must be 64 bit processes. The error indicates that your project isn't configured properly yet. Please change your project platform target into x64:

[image: 64bit]

Also, make sure that all referenced libraries are x64 too.

Comment: The project platform target is configured to x64 but still the same issue.

Comment: In your screenshot it says MSIL, that's confusing

Comment: After your comment, I have changed the platform and now the warnings disappeared, but still the deployment fails.

Comment: Check your output tab under "Build". Usually it'll indicate what went wrong in one of the last several lines there.